# Grails 3 - Add font resource folder

Tags: grails, fonts, resources

I can't find where I can tell grails to include a font folder with some font-face (font-awesome). In past version, it would be include in the config.groovy file, but it don't seems like it have one in the version 3. Where can I put this configuration to tell grails to take count of this folder when generating my views?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am assuming you are used to using the resources plugin and not the asset pipeline which is what Grails 3 uses by default. From the upgrade guide:

> Step 7 - Migrate Static Assets not handled by Asset Pipeline If you
>   have static assets in your web-app directory of your Grails 2.x
>   application such as HTML files, TLDs etc. these need to be moved. For
>   public assets such as static HTML pages and so on these should go in
>   src/main/resources/public.
>
> TLD descriptors and non public assets should go in
>   src/main/resources/WEB-INF.
>
> As noted earlier, src/main/webapp folder can also be used for this
>   purpose but it is not recommended.

This means you will need to pass your static resources through the asset pipeline plugin, installed by default in Grails 3. What is the [asset pipeline](http://bertramdev.github.io/asset-pipeline/)?

> The Grails Asset-Pipeline is a plugin used for managing and processing
>   static assets in Grails applications. Asset-Pipeline functions include
>   processing and minification of both CSS and JavaScript files. It is
>   also capable of being extended to compile custom static assets, such
>   as CoffeeScript or LESS.

Create a folder in your project at the following location:

```
grails-app/assets/fonts
```

Read the documentation on [linking to assets](http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#linking) and plugins.

> Plugins 
>   Plugins also can have the same "grails-app/assets" folder and
>   their URL mapping is also the same. This means it can be more
>   important to ensure unique naming / path mapping between plugins. This
>   is also powerful in the sense that a plugin can add helper manifests
>   to be used within your apps like jquery, bootstrap, font-awesome, and
>   more.
>
> These plugins also differ in the fact that the assets within their
>   web-app directory also become available under a similar structure

If you follow those directions you should be able to require the font-awesome resource in your GSP pages. You will need to spend a little time learning the asset pipeline. There is another option, you could also use the [font awesome plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/font-awesome-resources).

Comment: Thanks man! Your advices help me a lot! But I founded great explanation on this article http://www.technologyscout.net/2015/07/adding-assets-in-grails-3/ too. Very likely yours!

Comment: That is a very helpful blog post and glad you were able to solve your problem.

Comment: The "linking to assets" link is broken!

Comment: Updated the link @Alexander Suraphel. They moved the asset pipeline usage documentation.

Answer (score 4):

For the asset pipeline to know about the grails-app/assets/fonts directory, add `includes = ["fonts/*"]` to build.gradle, like this:

```
assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
    includes = ["fonts/*"]
}
```

At first my fonts were still not showing up until after I did a `grails clean`.